# cannot exit ipython feature dialog in spyder ipython console

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, spyder

I have started to use ipython in spyder with python 2.7 and i am on a PC 64bit with windows 8. Everything started out fine and I was doing this tutorial to get acquainted with pandas: (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb)

when I type for expample "zip?" the feature dialog shows up and I can continue coding below that dialog, however when I do the same thing for "df.to_csv?" i get the feature dialog and I can no longer put code below. How can I get out of this feature dialog??

I have searched quite a while now without success. please help me out!

here is exactly what I have put in the ipython console:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
names = ['Bob','Jessica','Mary','John','Mel']
births = [968, 155, 77, 578, 973]
zip?
BabyDataSet = zip(names, births)
df = DataFrame(data = BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])
df.to_csv?
```

when run ipython in the command prompt I do not have that problem. I see the help dialog, but below I can continue coding.

Thanks for your help, 
I am not an expert, so please keep it simple...

Answer (score 0):

When your focus is on the IPython console, press `q` and you will return to the console.

But if you are using Spyder, I would even advice not to use this but the **object inspector** of Spyder itself (in the standard window layout above the console). When you type the `?` after `df.to_csv` (only typing it, not pressing enter!) the help of this function will already be shown (and nicely rendered) in the object inspector. Also pressing `Ctrl+I` when your cursor is at a function will bring up the help info of this function.

Comment: That is great! Thanks for the hint!! I hope it can help also other beginners here. Now I see: in the menu Tools -> Preferences -> Keyboardshortcuts there it is listed.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I'm glad you find our Object Inspector useful. It'll have a *Usage* message in the next release to let people know how to use it.